# New job listing ad click handler receives events

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

1. Have a question page with a new style job ad.
2. Attempt to vote to close. The close button in the dialog is blocked by the ad.

The z-index of the `a` in ad is 100 where the dialog is 10. Luckily the dialog is movable.

Comment: I was about to report this as well. The Close button in the dialog happens to be in front of the ad, and when you click the Close button, the ad receives the click instead and instead of voting to close, you are launched into a new page about the job being advertised.

Comment: This is a really annoying bug. It has happened repeatedly about 10 times now; the only solution is remembering to drag the close dialog to the left far enough so that it doesn't overlap the job ad before clicking the close button. This is a major goof, when trying to close or migrate a question results in a click through to the ad and a loading of the job post in the browser tab (which as a side effect discards your close vote and any custom close reason text you've written).

Comment: This is extremely problematic because on some screen devices you can't actually drag the dialog away from the close button. Some of us answer questions from Netbooks / Phablets (occasionally)

Comment: Just noticed this on my iPad. Had to click the *very* small part of the Close button that just stuck out beyond the ad.

Comment: I'm unable to repro here, but I might not have the right screen size to repro. Can you tell me what resolution you're encountering this at?

Comment: Scratch that, just reproduced. Fix incoming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z-index` for that `<a>` in the new job ads has been fixed. It should no longer render on top of the dialogs on the page.

Sorry about that, that was overlooked when I was styling the new ads. That'll teach me to push out code on a Friday afternoon...